# Tooltip when pointing to question links ends with '&hellip;'

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions

The tooltip that appears when I point to a question link on the front page always ends in `&hellip;` instead of a proper ellipsis:

[image: '&hellip' at end of question tooltip]

I can reproduce this problem on both Firefox 6 and Internet Explorer 9 running on Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.  Can someone look into this?

Comment: This had happened before, acc to @MarcG it's a 'feature' with the razor engine http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98889/why-the-heck-do-i-see-so-many-hellips also reported on Meta.SO http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104230/attack-of-the-double-encoded-hellip-part-n

Comment: It's happens with Chrome 13.0.7 too.

Comment: this is a dupe, so http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104230/attack-of-the-double-encoded-hellip-part-n/104255#104255